# What is the proper number formatting for a legal document from the Supreme court?

Tags: american-english, numbers, legalese, style-manuals, ordinal-numbers

Do federally-issued legal documents in the USA require numbers spelt out, or in number form?

[I took a look at this site](https://lawlibguides.luc.edu/c.php?g=610824&p=4239812#20466708)  concerning ***Citation, Grammar and Style Guides*** from Loyola School of Law, but it was a little  difficult to wade through.

I am reading the recent Dobb's ruling from the Supreme Court re Roe v Wade, and while some spelt-out numbers are edited to provide numeral  formatting, other portions retain the spelt out parts. It does not seem very consistent.

Is this by a style guide, or is this legalese? And why the inconsistency? It all seems a little rushed, and ill-considered...compare the yellow circles with the green ones.

[From CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2022/06/us/supreme-court-abortion-dobbs-decision-changes/) "Track changes between the abortion decision and the leaked draft"

> It began by noting that, at the time of enactment, only ***six*** countries besides the United States permit [ed] nontherapeutic or elective abortion-on-demand after the ***twentieth*** week of gestation [...]

> The legislature then found that at *five 5* or *six 6* gestational age an unborn human being's heart begins beating; at *eight 8* weeks the unborn human being begins to move about in the womb; at nine 9 weeks all basic physiological functions are present; at *ten 10*

Verified Image below

[image]

***So is there some special style guide that we mere mortals do not have access to, or is it just arbitrary and possibly due to clerks not having their dockets in a row?***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to Law.SE.

Answer (score 1):

A book was published in 2016 called *The Supreme Court’s Style Guide.*

[https://www.amazon.com/Supreme-Courts-Style-Guide/dp/099111633X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/099111633X)

The Court’s opinions as released to the public are final decisions, but the hard-copy version, which may include a few corrections, comes a few weeks later, according to the Court’s web page. The hard copy is the definitive reference.